# java function returning values via custom exception is a good approach?

Tags: java, return

Is java function returning values via exception a best practice or does it have any disadvantage?  My requirement is a java DAO function returns me a collection of data with limited size(basically lazy loading). I need to get total size of the collection. So what I thought was if I pass a flag to the java DAO function for total count, the challenge thing was to return the count from the java DAO function.  Is it ok to get the count through exception? Is this a good approach?  Any other solution is always welcome.

EDIT:
The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case: I have an action layer and a dao layer. Now in action layer I have used around "5 (if , else) condition" to get different types of data collection WITH limited count from DB. Now my next action task was to get the total count of the collection WITHOUT limited count. How to do was the question avoiding more number of if conditions. So what I thought was to use EXCEPTION to return total count and handle clean in action layer. Here I need either total count or data list.

Answer (score 4):

> is java function returning values via exception a best practice

I would not consider this good practice. [Use Exceptions for exceptional circumstances only, not when handling normal program flow.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AvoidExceptionsWheneverPossible)

> the challenge thing was to return the count from the java DAO function

You can always return a container instead of a single value. Add all values you want to return to the container object and then return the container object:

```
public MyContainer getDAOListAsContainer() {
   MyList myList = ...;   // get the list from somewhere
   int mySize = 42;
   return new MyContainer(myList, mySize);
}
```

Besides that, java collection classes usually "know" their size already through their `size()` method. So if you already have something like a `List`, you can get its size like

```
List result = getDAOList();
// result.size() now contains the number of elements
```

Comment: The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case:

Comment: The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case: I have an action layer and a dao layer. Now in action layer I have used around "5 (if , else) condition" to get different types of data collection WITH limited count from DB. Now my next action task was to get the total count of the collection WITHOUT limited count. How to do was the question avoiding more number of if conditions. So what I thought was to use EXCEPTION to return total count and handle clean in action layer. Here I need either total count or data list.

Answer (score 2):

An exception indicates exceptional behavior - that is, something happened that you didn't expect would.  All you know about the state of the application is that something went wrong; you don't actually know if the count is coming back (since the database may be correct, but your ORM layer is inconsistent).

I wouldn't consider getting any information outside of, "Hey - something's wrong with the DAO" from the exception.

Comment: The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case: I have an action layer and a dao layer. Now in action layer I have used around "5 (if , else) condition" to get different types of data collection WITH limited count from DB. Now my next action task was to get the total count of the collection WITHOUT limited count. How to do was the question avoiding more number of if conditions. So what I thought was to use EXCEPTION to return total count and handle clean in action layer. Here I need either total count or data list.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider it a good approach.

Using exceptions in order to obtain information or even control flow has an impact on the performance as java needs to collect a considerable amount of information during the process of creating and throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a POJO to encapsulate both and then return.

```
void CollectionAndSize methodInDAO(boolean neededCollection, boolean neededTotalCount)
{
CollectionAndSize cas = new CollectionAndSize();

//Some code here.
if(neededCollection)
    { 
    collection = getLimitedCollection();
    cas.setCollection(collection);
    } 

if(neededTotalCount)
    { 
    totalRecords = = getnumberOfRecords();
    cas.setTotalRecords(totalRecords );
    }
return cas;
}
```

Comment: The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case: I have an action layer and a dao layer. Now in action layer I have used around "5 (if , else) condition" to get different types of data collection WITH limited count from DB. Now my next action task was to get the total count of the collection WITHOUT limited count. How to do was the question avoiding more number of if conditions. So what I thought was to use EXCEPTION to return total count and handle clean in action layer. Here I need either total count or data list.

Comment: modified according to your usecase. Exception way is in no way of clean way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice - nobody typically uses exceptions this way.
So it will be confusing / annoying later for people maintaining the code.

Comment: The reason to go with exception was: Let me explain the use case: I have an action layer and a dao layer. Now in action layer I have used around "5 (if , else) condition" to get different types of data collection WITH limited count from DB. Now my next action task was to get the total count of the collection WITHOUT limited count. How to do was the question avoiding more number of if conditions. So what I thought was to use EXCEPTION to return total count and handle clean in action layer. Here I need either total count or data list.